# call an element outside of another div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the two div

```
<div align="left">
<a class="bb" value="Test1">
<a class="bb" value="Test2">
<a class="bb" value="Test3">
<a class="bb" value="Test4">
<a class="bb" value="Test5"><a class="bb" value="Test6">

</div>
<div align="right">
<input type="text" name="c" id="c">
</div>
```

i want to get the value of second div input field when i am doing a jquery action of the following

```
$(".bb").click(function() {
 var ele = $(this); 
 var c = $(this).parent().next('div > #c').val(); - but it is always picking the first value in class and poininting to the next element 
});
```

how can i make sure that ioy picks the value of the div outside the first div properly

Comment: Are you saying you have multiple elements with same **id** `#c`?

Comment: Er... why not just `var c = $("#c").val();`?

Comment: You need to close your `a` elements

Comment: Have you repeated the same `id="c"` on multiple elements? If so, that's part of your problem

Comment: event bubbling?

Comment: the  `a` tags are closed, i forgot to paste it, the jquery is running on `bb` class, so clicked on any `a` tag having `bb` should run, but the `c` should be able to load its data if specified, i am always getting `undefined`, the way i am using it

Comment: `id="c"` is not specified multiple times, its just one time

Comment: You need to clean up your HTML: There is no `align` on div tags, you need an `href` for a-tags (or use a button if there is no link). You need to close your a-tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, note that your HTML has several issues. You've stated in the comments that this is just from quickly creating an example in the question, so I'll gloss over that.

The issue with your current logic is that the sibling of the parent `div` will never match the `div > #c` selector. You cannot look for descendants of a sibling in a `next()` selector. To fix this combine `next()` and `find()` like this:

```js
$(".bb").click(function() {
  var ele = $(this);
  var c = $(this).parent().next('div').find('#c').val();
  console.log(c);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div align="left">
  <a href="#" class="bb" value="Test1">Test1</a>
  <a href="#" class="bb" value="Test2">Test2</a>
  <a href="#" class="bb" value="Test3">Test3</a>
  <a href="#" class="bb" value="Test4">Test4</a>
  <a href="#" class="bb" value="Test5">Test5</a>
  <a href="#" class="bb" value="Test6">Test6</a>
</div>
<div align="right">
  <input type="text" name="c" id="c" value="foo" />
</div>
```

***However***, as the element you're trying to target has an `id` on it the entire point of traversing the DOM is redundant. Just select the element directly by that `id` as they *have* to be unique within the DOM:

```js
$(".bb").click(function() {
  var c = $('#c').val();
  console.log(c);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div align="left">
  <a href="#" class="bb" value="Test1">Test1</a>
  <a href="#" class="bb" value="Test2">Test2</a>
  <a href="#" class="bb" value="Test3">Test3</a>
  <a href="#" class="bb" value="Test4">Test4</a>
  <a href="#" class="bb" value="Test5">Test5</a>
  <a href="#" class="bb" value="Test6">Test6</a>
</div>
<div align="right">
  <input type="text" name="c" id="c" value="foo" />
</div>
```